# Extending base class multiple times using same name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is mostly a design question. I am creating a Laravel app and cannot figure out the design to use to provide what I want. My Laravel application is completely modular, with every module having their own routes, config, Models, Controllers and everything, and them loading in using a `ServiceProvider`.

My problem is as follows:

I have a `Pages` module, which consists of a `Page` model (`Eloquent\Model`). This module is used by other models to generate out pages.
I want other modules to extend that model. So for example, if I have `PagesFiles` module, then the `Page` module should have a way to access its files, like `Page->files`, which I could easily do within the actual `Pages` module with a simple relationship. But I need that method to be available without actually coding anything into the `Page` class, but from within other classes.

I also cannot just do `PageWithFiles extends Page`, because there will be multiple Modules extending same `Page` module providing it with additional functionality.

Please do let me know, if I can provide more information to help me solve this design problem.

Comment: I don't see a problem. You can extend classes multiple times. Do you know how many times `Eloquent` gets extended for each model? A lot.

Comment: Looks like you want class `Page` to be extended only partially by other features. That's not how inheritance works, unless someone invents siblings to share inheritance in OOP. Maybe what you want can be achieved through Traits. Laravel sometimes makes hard usage of Traits. That way, you can separate the functionalities you want into various traits.

Comment: aynber, Yes, but the modules will be loaded in dynamically, it won't work if I chain the inherits.

@MarcoAurélioDeleu, Is it possible to load on Traits dynamically onto a class?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance. Also you could use Dependecy injection, so you could pass the class you need and use it as you like inside your new classes. It's will also help you to stick with SOLID principles.

Comment: @jaro1989 I thought of Factory & Decorators pattern to return me a Page class with the required functionality dynamically. But I think Dependency Injection could be a really nice solution too, I will try that, thanks! :)